# How can I add background color to the front cover of a memoir?

Tags: tikz-pgf, memoir, geometry

I am trying to create a customized front cover for my memoir document using TikZ. I would like to add background color to the first page. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={210mm,297mm},
  left=25mm,right=25mm,
  bindingoffset=0mm, top=25mm,bottom=25mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\fill[blue] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\node [yellow] at (current page.center) {{\HUGE \textbf{CUSTOM FRONT COVER}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the above code produces a very thin white line around the page. How could I get rid of this white frame?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't a viewer issue? I don't get a white line.

Comment: I dont have white thin border. The full page is blue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it turned out that the problem was a viewer issue, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/678663/how-can-i-add-background-color-to-the-front-cover-of-a-memoir/678665?noredirect=1#comment1684390_678665

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the viewer your are using, not the LaTeX code.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using tikz, you could change the page colour on your title page to blue and then to white (or whatever colour you like) on the page after your title page:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={210mm,297mm},
  left=25mm,right=25mm,
  bindingoffset=0mm, top=25mm,bottom=25mm}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{blue}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
%\fill[blue] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\node [yellow] at (current page.center) {{\HUGE \textbf{CUSTOM FRONT COVER}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\AddToHookNext{shipout/after}{\pagecolor{white}}


\clearpage
test

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your method still produces a white frame (it's very annoying). Not sure if it is a viewer issue (the frame is seen in both TeXworks and Adobe Acrobat Pro). Any further hint on how to fix this?

Comment: @Tonechas I can't see any white frame with mac Preview.app, texstudio, skim or adobe reader.

Comment: I opened the pdf with Firefox and I didn't see any white frame. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Tonechas You're welcome!